# Jcrop with set parameters

Tags: javascript, jcrop

I use a submit form to send the name and size type of picture to a php file where i use jcrop on it.What i want is to use the "selection can be moved" option from tutorial nr5 of Jcrop (and disable the other options) and the size of the jcrop field is set by the size parameter sent from the form. Anyone an expert at Jcrop? cause i'm a newbie and don't understand the code. PLS HELP.

```
if( (isset($_POST['tip_imagine']))&&(isset($_POST['alt-rol'])) ){
        $num=$_POST['alt-rol'];
        $size=$_POST['tip_imagine'];
                                if($size==0){
                                    $width=400;
                                    $height=118;

                                }
                                if($size==1){
                                    $width=500;
                                    $height=400;

                                }   

                                if($size==2){
                                    $height=200;
                                    $width=188; 

                                }   
                                if($size==3){   
                                    $height=195;
                                    $width=340;

                                }
                                if($size==4){
                                    $width=500;
                                    $height=400;

                                }   
                                if($size==5){
                                    $width=1280;
                                    $height=800;

                                }   
    }   
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_tools.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($){



        // The variable jcrop_api will hold a reference to the
        // Jcrop API once Jcrop is instantiated.
        var jcrop_api;

        // In this example, since Jcrop may be attached or detached
        // at the whim of the user, I've wrapped the call into a function
        initJcrop();

        // The function is pretty simple
        function initJcrop()//{{{
        {
          // Hide any interface elements that require Jcrop
          // (This is for the local user interface portion.)
          $('.requiresjcrop').hide();

          // Invoke Jcrop in typical fashion
          $('#target').Jcrop({
            onRelease: releaseCheck
          },function(){

            jcrop_api = this;
            jcrop_api.animateTo([100,100,400,300]);

            // Setup and dipslay the interface for "enabled"
            $('#can_click,#can_move,#can_size').attr('checked','checked');
            $('#ar_lock,#size_lock,#bg_swap').attr('checked',false);
            $('.requiresjcrop').show();

          });

        };
        //}}}

        // Use the API to find cropping dimensions
        // Then generate a random selection
        // This function is used by setSelect and animateTo buttons
        // Mainly for demonstration purposes
        function getRandom() {
          var dim = jcrop_api.getBounds();
          return [
            Math.round(Math.random() * dim[0]),
            Math.round(Math.random() * dim[1]),
            Math.round(Math.random() * dim[0]),
            Math.round(Math.random() * dim[1])
          ];
        };

        // This function is bound to the onRelease handler...
        // In certain circumstances (such as if you set minSize
        // and aspectRatio together), you can inadvertently lose
        // the selection. This callback re-enables creating selections
        // in such a case. Although the need to do this is based on a
        // buggy behavior, it's recommended that you in some way trap
        // the onRelease callback if you use allowSelect: false
        function releaseCheck()
        {
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowSelect: true });
          $('#can_click').attr('checked',false);
        };

        // Attach interface buttons
        // This may appear to be a lot of code but it's simple stuff
        $('#setSelect').click(function(e) {
          // Sets a random selection
          jcrop_api.setSelect(getRandom());
        });
        $('#animateTo').click(function(e) {
          // Animates to a random selection
          jcrop_api.animateTo(getRandom());
        });
        $('#release').click(function(e) {
          // Release method clears the selection
          jcrop_api.release();
        });
        $('#disable').click(function(e) {
          // Disable Jcrop instance
          jcrop_api.disable();
          // Update the interface to reflect disabled state
          $('#enable').show();
          $('.requiresjcrop').hide();
        });
        $('#enable').click(function(e) {
          // Re-enable Jcrop instance
          jcrop_api.enable();
          // Update the interface to reflect enabled state
          $('#enable').hide();
          $('.requiresjcrop').show();
        });
        $('#rehook').click(function(e) {
          // This button is visible when Jcrop has been destroyed
          // It performs the re-attachment and updates the UI
          $('#rehook,#enable').hide();
          initJcrop();
          $('#unhook,.requiresjcrop').show();
          return false;
        });
        $('#unhook').click(function(e) {
          // Destroy Jcrop widget, restore original state
          jcrop_api.destroy();
          // Update the interface to reflect un-attached state
          $('#unhook,#enable,.requiresjcrop').hide();
          $('#rehook').show();
          return false;
        });

        // Hook up the three image-swapping buttons
        $('#img1').click(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setImage('demo_files/sago.jpg');
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ bgOpacity: .6 });
          return false;
        });
        $('#img2').click(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setImage('demo_files/pool.jpg');
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ bgOpacity: .6 });
          return false;
        });
        $('#img3').click(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setImage('demo_files/sago.jpg',function(){
            this.setOptions({
              bgOpacity: 1,
              outerImage: 'demo_files/sagomod.jpg'
            });
            this.animateTo(getRandom());
          });
          return false;
        });

        // The checkboxes simply set options based on it's checked value
        // Options are changed by passing a new options object

        // Also, to prevent strange behavior, they are initially checked
        // This matches the default initial state of Jcrop

        $('#can_click').change(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowSelect: !!this.checked });
          jcrop_api.focus();
        });
        $('#can_move').change(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowMove: !!this.checked });
          jcrop_api.focus();
        });
        $('#can_size').change(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowResize: !!this.checked });
          jcrop_api.focus();
        });
        $('#ar_lock').change(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setOptions(this.checked?
            { aspectRatio: 4/3 }: { aspectRatio: 0 });
          jcrop_api.focus();
        });
        $('#size_lock').change(function(e) {
          jcrop_api.setOptions(this.checked? {
            minSize: [ 80, 80 ],
            maxSize: [ 350, 350 ]
          }: {
            minSize: [ 0, 0 ],
            maxSize: [ 0, 0 ]
          });
          jcrop_api.focus();
        });


      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the  following in jcrop.js file :

```
allowSelect: false,
allowMove: true,
allowResize: false,
```

and on page :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#selectedimage').Jcrop({
         setSelect:[ 275,60,50,15 ]
    });
});
```

You can change value in setselect  and size of selected area will change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer at least partially : I have  edited the jquery.Jcrop.js file so when loaded the default will be false for allowSelect and allowResize.

```
// Basic Settings
    allowSelect: false,
    allowMove: true,
    allowResize: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who got here by googling 'jcrop api focus not working'

make sure you call `api.enable()` first!